# Strange powerbi behaviour cannot explore dataset

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I am sending data from Stream Analytics to powerbi.
Most of the time it works fine but from time to time I upload large amounts of data for test purposes. I notice that my SU utilization is 100% and get error messages in Stream Analytics saying that I might encounter strange behaviour because of that.
And in most of these cases when I goto powerbi I see my datasets but when I try to explore them I get nothing. The table page is not opened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PowerBI is currently in preview, and there are still some silent bugs here and there.

Two silent bugs that come to mind are:

1. PowerBI currently does not support embedded JSON objects. If a single entry goes into a PowerBI that has an embedded object, it will break the entire table.
2. Table schemas are set in stone. If later you decided you wanted to change your schema (by changing the select statement in Stream Analytics), you have to output to an entirely different table. If two different schemas go into the same table, the table will break and fail to load as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Best to connect with the Stream Analytics folks on this.  If you've maximized your SA jobs, you might try scaling up your SA implementation.  You should also double check how much data you're sending to Power BI and how often.  You want to have a tumbling windows of 1 second or greater for most purposes (Power BI updates the dashboards every second) and choose an appropriate amount of data so you don't get throttled on the Power BI side (see restrictions: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/pricing).
HTH,
-Lukasz